# How to use router in vue composition api?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I defined a route in vue:

```
/users/:userId
```

Which point to UserComponent:

```
<template>
 <div>{{username}}</div>
</template>
```

and I use `computed` from `@vue/composition-api` to get the data.

the problem is when the route change to another `userId`, by navigate to another user, the user in the html template not changed as what I expected. also it doesn't do redirect when the the user is not in the list.

So what I can do to fix that?

here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div>{{username}}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { computed, defineComponent, ref, getCurrentInstance } from '@vue/composition-api';

export const useUsername = ({ user }) => {
  return { username: user.name };
};

export default defineComponent({
  setup(props, { root }) {
    const vm = getCurrentInstance();

    const userToLoad = computed(() => root.$route.params.userId);
    const listOfUsers = [
      { userId: 1, name: 'user1' },
      { userId: 2, name: 'user2' },
    ];

    const user = listOfUsers.find((u) => u.userId === +userToLoad.value);
    if (!user) {
      return root.$router.push('/404');
    }

    const { username } = useUsername({ user });

    return { username };
  },
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just do this:

```js
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export default {
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute();
    // Now you can access params like:
    console.log(route.params.id);
  }
};
```

Comment: useRoute is not available in vue 2 router. it's not working for me. is this intended for vue 3?

Comment: I see you are using Vue 3 Though

Comment: No he is not. He use `@vue/composition-api` which is a composition API as a plugin for Vue 2

Comment: ahhh, sorry i didn't see that the snippet was cut off

Answer (score 15):

From the `vue-router` documentation:

```js
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default {
    setup() {
        const router = useRouter()
        const route = useRoute()

        function pushWithQuery(query) {
            if (!user) {
                router.push({
                    name: '404',
                    query: {
                        ...route.query
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was for Vue 2 and the composition-api package

Comment: Ill try to edit my answer so i reflect vue 2 @Matthias Sommer

Answer (score 7):

A had the same problem. I use vue 2 and @vue/composition-api

My resolution:

Created: src/router/migrateRouterVue3.js

```
import { reactive } from '@vue/composition-api';
import router from './index';

const currentRoute = reactive({
  ...router.currentRoute,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  Object.keys(to).forEach(key => {
    currentRoute[key] = to[key];
  });
  next();
});

// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export function useRoute() {
  return currentRoute;
}
```

after that, I can usage:

```
// import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { useRoute } from '@/router/migrateRouterVue3';
```

---

Resolution for you:

```
// replace:
// const userToLoad = computed(() => root.$route.params.userId);
// to:  
import { useRoute } from '@/router/migrateRouterVue3';
//...
const route = useRoute();
const userToLoad = computed(() => route.params.userId);
```

Comment: beforeEach won't work properly if the user enters the route directly and you're trying to access params. Move the hook to afterEach and remove the next(). It's going to be very rare that you need this data before beforeCreate (which is the default lifecycle of composition API setup() )

Comment: @Trent function next is required for beforeEach. And hook beforeEach work for directly enter.

Comment: I was not saying that next() is not required for beforeEach, it definitely is. I was saying that it should be changed to afterEach (which you don't need "next" for). If you navigate directly on the route (e.g. type the full URL into the browser and press enter) using beforeEach won't trigger for THIS particular problem. afterEach will always trigger whether you are navigating into the route from another route, OR entering directly on the route with no previous route.

Comment: Yes. I see what do you want to say. But don't understand why do you think that direct route doesn't work for beforeEach?
example: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-shockley-ukdme?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: OK, turns out I had beforeEach already attached the router doing work on direct entry which was cancelling out the useRoute method above. Changing to afterEach solved it, but not for the reason I thought. Thanks Andrei for helping debug my issue too :)

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the parameters as props to your components. Props are reactive by default.

This is how the route configuration could look like:

```
      {
        path: '/users/:userId',
        name: Users,
        component: YourComponent
      },
```

You can then use the props in your component with `watchEffect()`

```
<template>
  <div>{{username}}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { computed, defineComponent, ref, getCurrentInstance, watchEffect } from '@vue/composition-api';

export const useUsername = ({ user }) => {
  return { username: user.name };
};

export default defineComponent({
  props: {userId: {type: String, required: true },
  setup(props, { root }) {
    const vm = getCurrentInstance();
    const user = ref()

    const userToLoad = computed(() => props.userId);
    const listOfUsers = [
      { userId: 1, name: 'user1' },
      { userId: 2, name: 'user2' },
    ];

    watchEffect(() => user.value = listOfUsers.find((u) => u.userId === +userToLoad.value))
    
    if (!user) {
      return root.$router.push('/404');
    }

    const { username } = useUsername({ user });

    return { username };
  },
});

</script>
```

`watchEffect()` will run immediately when defined and when reactive dependencies.change

Comment: You need to setup props: true to route configuration

Comment: Even if you set [props: true](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components) (you did not) the child component(s) don't get the params from route.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function useRoute() {
  const vm = getCurrentInstance()
  if (!vm) throw new Error('must be called in setup')

  return vm.proxy.$route
}
```

https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/630

Comment: In this case, (`route = useRoute()`) route is not reactive

Answer (score 2):

The following `useRoute` hook will make `route` reactive so that it's doable:

```
const route = useRoute();
const fooId = computed(()=>route.params.fooId);
```

```js
let currentRoute = null;
export const useRoute = () => {
  const self = getCurrentInstance(); 
  const router = self.proxy.$router;
  if (!currentRoute) {
    const route = { ...self.proxy.$route };
    const routeRef = shallowRef(route);
    const computedRoute = {};
    for (const key of Object.keys(routeRef.value)) {
      computedRoute[key] = computed(() => routeRef.value[key]);
    }
    router.afterEach((to) => {
      routeRef.value = to;
    });
    currentRoute = reactive(computedRoute);
  }
  return currentRoute;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`vue2-helpers`](https://github.com/ambit-tsai/vue2-helpers) package provides a `useRoute` function you can use in Vue 2.7 (and 2.6, 2.5 also).

#### Installation

```bash
# Vue 2.7
$ npm install vue2-helpers@2
# Vue 2.5 and 2.6
$ npm install vue2-helpers@1
```

#### Usage

```js
import { useRoute } from 'vue2-helpers/vue-router';

const route = useRoute();
const id: string | undefined = route.params.id;
```

Answer (score -3):

Add please this code: watchEffect(() => userToLoad);