# useRoute is undefined

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to use `useRoute` in a vue 2.6 application but it's undefined:

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
console.log('useRoute is',useRoute)
```

My package.json:

```
"@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
"vue": "^2.6.12",
"vue-router": "^3.4.8",
```

I could not find anything in the [documentation](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html) telling me this would not work.

I can see that current version is 4 but that depends on [vue 3](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/master/package.json#L55) I don't have that version and am afraid everything will break when I update. And there is no need for this dependency since I have composition api installed.

Just like most of vue's "documentation" the [useRoute](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#useroute) api doc seems to be missing since what version this function is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no useRouter in [vue router](https://router.vuejs.org/) only in [vue router next](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/) I know both pages look like they are for `vue-router` and none of the `next` content would suggest it's not for vue-router but the url indicates it's for [vue router next](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next).

It's nice to be prepared for the future but currently vue 2 is still installed when doing a [yarn add vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue) so it would be nice if the documentation had a header indicating this is about a completely different project that just happens to have the same name and logos.

I suspect looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60755676/1641941) I'm sht out of luck trying to get vue-route parameters in the composition-api setup function.

**Update**

With provide/inject I can get route props from every component:

```
{
  path: `/:country(${
    Object.keys(config.countries).join('|')
  })?/:locale(${
    Object.keys(config.languages).join('|')
  })?`,
  props:true,//need to have this
  component: Root,
```

My Root component has:

```
props: {
  locale: String,//this is mandatory
},
setup(props) {
  const loc=ref(props.locale);
  watch(()=>props.locale,
  (current)=>{
    loc.value=current
  }
  )
  provide('locale', loc);
},
```

In the child component(s):

```
setup(){
  // locale is an observable
  const locale = inject('locale')
},
```