# Vue router in composition api?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router, vue-composition-api

In Nuxt 2.16, I'm trying to access the [`useRouter`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-router) composable with `import {useRouter} from 'vue-router'`, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60755676/how-to-use-router-in-vue-composition-api), but the import leaves `useRouter` undefined.

When I `import * as r from 'vue-router'` then `console.log(r, 'vue-router')` I get:

[image]

How should I access the router in this stack?

```bash
└─┬ nuxt@2.17.0
  └─┬ @nuxt/vue-app@2.17.0
    └── vue-router@3.6.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Import from `vue-router/composables`.  This folder contains `composables.js` and `composables.mjs`.  In my case, project.json has `"type": "module"` the mjs did not work, I needed to qualify the import with `.js`.

This solves it, the `.js` is required in my case:

```
import {useRouter} from 'vue-router/composables.js'
const router = useRouter()
router.push('/')
```

ref: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/21674

Comment: Could you make it clear that this is because Vue 2 does not natively have the Composition API?

Comment: Having to import a common js file instead of the module file may have something to do with how nuxt configures vite and how vue-router builds its modules.